# Rounded corners Image inside PageView keeping ratio Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rounded-corners, clip, flutter-pageview

I have a `PageView` with images list inside. I want to keep the image ratio and set a rounded corners to them.

Usually I had no problem to clip image inside simple list or single image.

But in this case, the `ClipRRect` is not wrapping the image and when I'm setting size to red `Container` nothing happened.

**Result :**

[image]

**Code :**

```
double maxiHeight = 250;
  List<Widget> postList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for(Post p in Model.instance.postList) {
      postList.add(post(p));
    }
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: maxiHeight,
      child: PageView(
          controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.5),
          children: postList
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget post(Post post) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Image.network(post.thumb, height: 50)
        )
    );
  }
```

**I want to keep my image ratio.**

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your code snippet, you are providing margin right 1st then wrapping with `ClipRRect`. Here the main Container is getting its size and then using margin, after wrapping with `ClipRRect` it is avoiding `10px` from right to Clip. And this is how we are getting current output.

But we want padding outside The Container and without border radius. Means after decorating the image, just provide some padding. You can follow this and using `fit: BoxFit.cover` will cover the widget size.

```dart
      Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  child: Container(
                    // margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),// not here
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Image.network(
                      // post.thumb,
                      "https://unsplash.it/1440/3040?random",
                      // fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                      height: 150,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Agree for the margin I was writing this sample quickly . But , I don't want to use Boxfit.cover , as I said in my question I want to keep the initial image ratio. with this box fit ratio is broken

Comment: Means the image will get exact size and have corner border?

Comment: Yes like in my screen shot but with rounded corners. it's working fine in simple list but not here and don't know why

Comment: You are using `height: 50`, does it  mean you like to have  fit  height ?

Comment: I've updated the widget, does it solve your issue now?

Comment: I wrote ```height: 50``` to prove that image size or container size doesn't affect the image at all.  In my screen shot , you'll see that the first image almost fill the available PageView height whereas the second is 2x less , and both have ```height: 50``` .   I just want the image match its ratio according pageView height and get rounded corners

Comment: Working with center. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 2):

With the following modified code it should work:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 500.0,
        child: ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: postList),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget post(String uri) {
    return Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
       child: ClipRRect(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
         child: Image.network(uri, fit: BoxFit.fitHeight)
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sorry can't use listView in this case

Comment: Why? PageView does not work with dynamic widths.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? With PageView you already define the width through the `viewportFraction` and then the height. PageView is not able to dynamically adjust the width of the children.

Comment: I already know about this and this is a good solution when using list. I need here to have the snap effect and a slow swiping control for a use case. I also know that plugins exist to mimic PageView behavior for lists but I had conflicts with this in my app.  Thanks for reply

Answer (score -1):

Try to add BoxFit.cover to Image.network widget

```
Widget post(Post post) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Image.network(post.thumb, height: 50, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
        )
    );
  }
```

Comment: I need to keep my image ratio I can't use box fit